# how to print random number 10 times in one line

Tags: python

I want to print 10 random number and I try this:

```
import random
number = 10
while number <= 10:
   print(random.randint(0,9))
   number += 1
```

but this print next number in the new line. I try below code to fix that but:

import random

```
number = 10
my_list = []
while number <= 10:
   my_list.append(random.randint(0,9))
   number += 1
print my_list
```

it display number with , and []

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: You meant to initialize `number` variable to zero right? you should edit your question then

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

randomlist = []

for i in range(0,5):
 n = random.randint(1,30)
 randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)
```

you can read more about it [here][1].

for the basics of printing:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-without-newline-python/

Comment: You should really correct the indentation

Answer (score 0):

To print without a new line you should edit the `end` argument which is set to newline by default, in. You could edit the print command in your first attempt to:

```
   print(random.randint(0,9), end = " ")
```